# how to use this type of json in Futur Builder snapshot

Tags: json, flutter, http, dart, future

i have this json file and want to use prices of AUDUSD in my Futur builder

json:

```
{"price":{"AUDUSD":0.76411,"EURUSD":1.17937,"GBPUSD":1.37923,"USDJPY":109.676},"timestamp":1616951788}
```

my Future Builder

```
 **FutureBuilder(
          future: getData(),
          builder: (buildcontext, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                  return Container(
                    child: Text(snapshot.data[i][////what should i put here]),**
```

my http request:

```
  **Future getData() async {
var url = 'http://------.com/curen.php';
var response = await http.get(url);
var responsebody = jsonDecode(response.body);
return (responsebody);
```

}**

Comment: It look like your json is not return a list? can you show the complete json example?

Comment: thats all of it bro

Comment: Because the json is not a list, would you consider not to use listView or change the json format?

Comment: No.cahanging format can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Based on the API provided by you in the comments.*

I made the following example, where I consume the API, and by using a FutureBuilder and display the information. Also create a model to better handle this information.

**Example:**

`API: https://api.openrates.io/latest`

`Package use: https://pub.dev/packages/http`

**1: Money Class**

```
class Money {
  Money({
    this.base,
    this.rates,
    this.date,
  });

  final String base;
  final Map<String, double> rates;
  final DateTime date;

  factory Money.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Money(
        base: json["base"],
        rates: Map.from(json["rates"])
            .map((k, v) => MapEntry<String, double>(k, v.toDouble())),
        date: DateTime.parse(json["date"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "base": base,
        "rates": Map.from(rates).map((k, v) => MapEntry<String, dynamic>(k, v)),
        "date":
            "${date.year.toString().padLeft(4, '0')}-${date.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${date.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}",
      };
}
```

**2: Widget Stateful**

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class ConsumeApiExample extends StatefulWidget {
  ConsumeApiExample({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ConsumeApiExampleState createState() => _ConsumeApiExampleState();
}

class _ConsumeApiExampleState extends State<ConsumeApiExample> {
  Money money = Money();

  Future<Money> getData() async {
    try {
      final res = await http.get('https://api.openrates.io/latest');

      if (res != null) {
        return Money.fromJson(jsonDecode(res.body));
      }

      return Money();
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: getData(),
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<Money> snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();
              return Container(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Center(
                      child: Text('Base: ${snapshot.data.base}'),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20),
                    ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: snapshot.data.rates.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          String key =
                              snapshot.data.rates.keys.elementAt(index);
                          double value =
                              snapshot.data.rates.values.elementAt(index);

                          return Center(child: Text('$key - $value'));
                        }),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

*Make sure you import your packages and classes, etc.*

**3: Results**

[image]

Comment: The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("price")

Comment: thanks for your answer i follow that but its gives me above error

Comment: @AliMahdiyar One question, are you using the second example and the information you receive is the object that you mentioned to us?

Comment: Yes thats it still cant reach this json objects

Comment: @ Felipe Vergara when i try the code below i recive null error
   child: Text(snapshot.data[i]['price']['AUDUSD'].toString()),

Comment: The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("AUD")